# Firebase-Function trigger guarantee

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there any documentation about the guarantee I have of my firebase function(s) to run for each event and in the correct order one by one?

I will explain by an example.
Let say I have an event with 4 people.
Each person is buying stuff for the event and insert it to the app, and the app calculates the amount each one should give the other to balance the score.

The calculation is done using Firebase function, using a trigger of "item" in the event.
So if person A spent 40$, the app should charge B. C and D with 10$ to A.
And if later B spent 20$, now C should give A 15$ and D give A 10$ and B 5$.

The question is, when I insert the second item, can I just calculate what was change (e.g. I know the balance score is 15$, because the current is 10' and I added 20/5) or it is possible that there was another item I may have missed and I need every time to sum all the expenses and calculate from scratch? (for example, a moment after B insert his expense to the app, C also did it, and now the function is triggered again, while I still didn't calculate B expense.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee about ordering of events.  That is something you'll have to figure out if it's important for your function, and deal with accordingly.

There is only an guarantee that a background function will be executed [at least once](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees), which means it could be invoked multiple times with the same event id and payload.  That is the way serverless functions work.

Comment: The order of events has no meaning in my case. The question remains, if in event I sends a number, and the function read value X somewhere, add the new number and write the new result. Is it possible that 2 instances of the function will run together, read the same X value, and then I will have false result? Also if I understand the meaning of 'at least once', that mean I can add my value to X twice? Is there a way to make sure several value either all written or non of them?

Comment: In your question you asked about guarantees to "run for each event and in the correct order one by one".  If you're asking about concurrency, yes, your function can definitely run concurrently on more than one server instance.  That's the only way that serverless architectures can scale to meet high load.

Comment: You are correct. That's what happens when you write at 1am. What I meant was if the function run for each event one *after* one, so if I'm updating a value, it will update before the second instance is running. If I understand what you are saying, I can be sure that will happens, and it possible that the 2 instance will read X, add their value and write it. But in that case, I have a major problem. Let say each function sum all the values, so the second instance will also sum the first value, who guarantee that the second result will be written after the first? 

Comment: You should use a transaction to ensure that two read-and-write operations do not clash.

Comment: I guess I will need to read about transactions. If I would use transactions, back to my first question. In that case, can I just update the shared value with the addition of the new value without be afraid that there is an event that didn't trigger the function? What about changing several values together (e. g. Either both done or both failed.

Comment: I'm afraid you have too many questions for a stack overflow comment.  You might be better helped by engaging in a discussion forum such as firebase-talk or Reddit.